# Draw line on mouse drag - which is best option Flash or Flex?

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I need help in selection between Flash and Flex.

I need to create an interface where user can draw lines, circles, highlight selected area with some color and add text to an image file. All these objects need to be drag-gable after added to the image. Which is the best option for this ? Flash or Flex ?

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what you're trying to do. Flex is built on Flash so at their base, they're the same technology.

Flash is probably easier to get to grips with, get the basics running quickly, knowing what's going on in the background and easier to find help for.

Flex's strength comes with the ability to quickly string together components and views to create a RIA without having to go through the trouble of creating everything from scratch. That said it adds about 200Kb to your project (if filesize is a problem).

Personally, I'd go for pure AS3 as it's what I'm quicker in and I like to know exactly what goes on in my program. If you need components, check out the minimalcomps project (http://www.minimalcomps.com/) which mimics the basic function of a lot of Flex's component while being much smaller in size. You can skin them as well I think if you need that.

Comment: I'm also thinking Flash as a good option, but not much expert in it. May I have some links where I can find good information. Anyways, thanks for reply.

Comment: Always keep the offical docs beside you as they're good: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/all-index-Symbols.html. For asking question, here, the http://flashkit.com/ boards, or the http://kirupa.com/ forums. For drawing lines, you're using the Graphics class: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html (on Shape, Sprite, or MovieClip), for dragging, use startDrag() and stopDrag() http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#startDrag() (Sprite or MovieClip)

Comment: For adding text to an image, add your image to a Sprite, then add a TextField with your text: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html